# Function defined in main program and public to other unit

Tags: pascal

In pascal, is there a way to make a function defined in main program and can be called by other units? I know the way to define a function in a unit can be called by the main program and other units. For some reason, I can only have two program files, one main program and one unit. One of the function cannot be defined in the unit. Thanks

Comment: It may depend on which variant of Pascal you are using. But you should be able to reference functions in your main program file by adding them to the *uses* list in the unit's *implementation* section.

Comment: You can only have two program files - do you mean source files? What actually happens if you try to have more?

Answer (score 0):

No and yes. No it is not possible in Pascal, but many compilers ( Free Pascal, maybe also Delphi) this can be circumvented by using the support to call external (non Pascal) code.

This is done declaring the variable as external in the unit with a certain linker name, and adding this linker name to the procedure's declaration in the mainmodule. The code will only meet up at the linker, so you are responsible for making declarations match.

Free Pascal uses this technique e.g. to export certain OS dependent routines from the System unit without making them visible.

E.g. for Free Pascal:

declaration of function main program:

```
 function Fpmkdir(path : pchar; mode: mode_t):cint; [public, alias : 'FPC_SYSC_MKDIR'];
   begin
    ...
   end;
```

declaration of the function in the unit:

```
Function  FpMkdir      (path : pChar; Mode: TMode):cInt;  external name 'FPC_SYSC_MKDIR';
```